# How to restrict creating "Android Folder" in USB?

Tags: android, frameworks, android-source

I have USB and when I inserted in my Android 10 tablet and when I turn on tablet, it's creating Android Folder. And inside the Android folder, package name is creating.

How to programatically remove Android Folder without creating it.

I know it's in frameworks but I don't know which code is creating Android Folder.

Comment: You should get SAF read/write access with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. After that you can read/delete files and folders. O jee.. and the folder is created by Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to create a script to delete these folders everytime you unmount the otg ..
but as of now there is no way to stop android from making these folders